# How to avoid repeating code in javascript

Tags: javascript

If we see the code, a word is always repeated (name, surname, position, nation).

```
const nameInput = document.getElementById('name-personalized')
let nameInputValue

const surnameInput = document.getElementById('surname-personalized')
let surnameInputValue

const positionInput = document.getElementById('position-personalized')
let positionInputValue

const nationInput = document.getElementById('nation-personalized')
let nationInputValue

nameInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value
    value = value.trim().toUpperCase()
    nameInputValue = value
})

surnameInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value
    value = value.trim().toUpperCase()
    surnameInputValue = value
})

positionInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value
    value = value.trim().toUpperCase()
    positionInputValue = value
})

nationInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value
    value = value.trim()
    nationInputValue = value
})
```

I want to write just that word, example:

```
avoidRepeat(name)
```

And let's say using a for cycle but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: for the code you've written in the question, it's hard (not possible at all really the way you've written it), since you have those variables `nameInputValue` etc - it's not possible to parameterise that

Comment: You need to know what is generic and what is specific. As said @JaromandaX, global variables cannot be dynamically referenced. You should use an indexed array (object in JS) to address those values according to a given key.

Comment: Here's my version: https://jsfiddle.net/k6nzLd43/

Comment: Given that one of the strings is not converted to uppercase, it wont be possible to apply the same action to all the elements. At minimum it will need to specify a mapping function (which would map the event to the trimmed/uppercase string). Also it might be better to read the string value in a callback rather than setting a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. Just wrap all the repeated code up in a function and pass the specifics as argument functions. I have removed the globals and replaced them with callback functions.

I'd say this solution is not optimal as it decreases code flexibility for the sake of making the code shorter. Passing two functions to the same function isn't ideal for readability.

You may find libraries like jquery, rxjs or even functional libraries like ramda could help reduce repetition and keep flexibility and readability intact.

```
<html>
<head><title>whatever</title></head>    
<body>
    <label for="name-personalized">name-personalized: </label><input type="text" id="name-personalized"><br>
    <label for="surname-personalized">surname-personalized: </label><input type="text" id="surname-personalized"><br>
    <label for="position-personalized">position-personalized: </label><input type="text" id="position-personalized"><br>
    <label for="nation-personalized">nation-personalized: </label><input type="text" id="nation-personalized">
</body>
<script>

function avoidRepeat(name, mapFn, cbFn) {
    const el = document.getElementById(name)
    el.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
        const val = mapFn(event.target.value);
        cbFn(val, event.target);
    })
}

const fnTrim = s => s.trim()
const fnTrimUpper = s => s.trim().toUpperCase()
const fnLog = (val, el) => console.log('for', el.getAttribute('id'), 'the value is ' + val)

avoidRepeat('name-personalized', fnTrimUpper, fnLog)
avoidRepeat('surname-personalized', fnTrimUpper, fnLog)
avoidRepeat('position-personalized', fnTrimUpper, fnLog)
avoidRepeat('nation-personalized', fnTrim, fnLog)

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You can get rid of `cbFn` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data in an object via the input's ID and just add an event listener to the inputs. Then accessed in bracket notation. I also removed `-personalized` from the keys.

**This code is all you need for all of those and even future inputs**

```
var values = {};

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

inputs.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    values[event.target.getAttribute("id").replace("-personalized","")] = event.target.value.trim()
  })
});
```

**You can access the data like this**

```
console.log(values["nation"]);
```

Comment: It's not always converted to uppercase.

Comment: @Amessihel good catch, I just removed that altogether.

Comment: Thanks, but you still need to convert to uppercase for name, surname and position. :)